# Append text in every line of txt in Python

Tags: python, text, formatting

I've a text file with many lines. I need to append to every line a text in Python.

Here an example:

**Text before:**

```
car
house
blog
```

**Text modified:**

```
car: [word]
house: [word]
blog: [word]
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to append `word` on each line this works fine

```
file_name = 'YOUR_FILE_NAME.txt' #Put here your file

with open(file_name,'r') as fnr:
    text = fnr.readlines()

text = "".join([line.strip() + ': [word]\n' for line in text])

with open(file_name,'w') as fnw:
    fnw.write(text)
```

But there are many ways to do it

Comment: with is definitely better than just opening and closing.

Comment: OTOH it is never a good idea to modify the original file - if you screw up, you have trouble starting over again

Answer (score 0):

Read the text in a list:

```
f = open("filename.dat")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

append text:

```
new_lines = [x.strip() + "text_to_append" for x in lines]  
# removes newlines from the elements of the list, appends 
# the text for each element of the list in a list comprehension
```

Edit:
for completness, a more pythonic solution with writing the text to a new file:

```
with open('filename.dat') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
new_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), text_to_append, '\n']) for x in lines]
with open('filename_new.dat', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_lines)
```